# show 3 star in alertdialog android

Tags: android

code below show 6 stars on alert dialog, what i want show only 3 stars, please give me some tip.

```
public void ShowDialog()
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final RatingBar rb = new RatingBar(this);
        popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
        rb.setRating(0);
        rb.setNumStars(3);      
        popDialog.setTitle("Vote!! ");
        popDialog.setView(rb);
        // Button OK
        popDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });
        popDialog.create();
        popDialog.show();


    }
```

Comment: i think you should set layoutparams for rating bar.

Comment: Have you set `Layoutparams` for `RatingBar`?

Answer (score 0):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        getActivity());
final RatingBar rb = new RatingBar(getActivity());
popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
rb.setRating(0);
rb.setNumStars(3);

popDialog.setTitle("Vote!! ");
popDialog.setView(rb);
// Button OK
popDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

popDialog.show();

// This is the trick
rb.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but how about rating ?, I set it to 3 but it didn't filled as 3 stars.

Comment: Try setting the rating after you adjust the width layout params.

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting the layout for RatingBar, Also try [rb.setMax()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setMax(int)) for maximum stars.

```
RatingBar rb = new RatingBar(context, null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);
  rb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  rb.setIsIndicator(true);
  rb.setNumStars(3);
  rb.setMax(3);
```